# Does "subscribe" call executes the Observable assignment expression

Tags: javascript, java, rxjs

I am new to Angular and RxJS. I am analysing the following extract from the Angular tutorial (ng-book2-book-angular-11-r77-code).
My question is when the call **`this.messages = this.updates`**...  (in the constructor method) executes - is it executing in the constructor or when `addMessage (message: Message)` is called?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../user/user.model';
import { Thread } from '../thread/thread.model';
import { Message } from '../message/message.model';

const initialMessages: Message[] = [];

interface IMessagesOperation extends Function {
  (messages: Message[]): Message[];
}

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {
  // a stream that publishes new messages only once
  newMessages: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();

  // `messages` is a stream that emits an array of the most up to date messages
  messages: Observable<Message[]>;

  // `updates` receives _operations_ to be applied to our `messages`
  // it's a way we can perform changes on *all* messages (that are currently
  // stored in `messages`)
  updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  // action streams
  create: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();
  markThreadAsRead: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.messages = this.updates
      // watch the updates and accumulate operations on the messages
      .scan((messages: Message[],
             operation: IMessagesOperation) => {
               return operation(messages);
             },
            initialMessages)
      // make sure we can share the most recent list of messages across anyone
      // who's interested in subscribing and cache the last known list of
      // messages
      .publishReplay(1)
      .refCount();
// `create` takes a Message and then puts an operation (the inner function)
// on the `updates` stream to add the Message to the list of messages.
//
// That is, for each item that gets added to `create` (by using `next`)
// this stream emits a concat operation function.
//
// Next we subscribe `this.updates` to listen to this stream, which means
// that it will receive each operation that is created
//
// Note that it would be perfectly acceptable to simply modify the
// "addMessage" function below to simply add the inner operation function to
// the update stream directly and get rid of this extra action stream
// entirely. The pros are that it is potentially clearer. The cons are that
// the stream is no longer composable.
this.create
  .map( function(message: Message): IMessagesOperation {
    return (messages: Message[]) => {
      return messages.concat(message);
    };
  })
  .subscribe(this.updates);

this.newMessages
  .subscribe(this.create);

// similarly, `markThreadAsRead` takes a Thread and then puts an operation
// on the `updates` stream to mark the Messages as read
this.markThreadAsRead
  .map( (thread: Thread) => {
    return (messages: Message[]) => {
      return messages.map( (message: Message) => {
        // note that we're manipulating `message` directly here. Mutability
        // can be confusing and there are lots of reasons why you might want
        // to, say, copy the Message object or some other 'immutable' here
        if (message.thread.id === thread.id) {
          message.isRead = true;
        }
        return message;
      });
    };
  })
  .subscribe(this.updates);

}

  // an imperative function call to this action stream
  addMessage(message: Message): void {
    this.newMessages.next(message);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, lazyNumber is assigned in the `constructor` and referenced in the `printNumber` method.

The expression isn't evaluated to 4 until it's called.

```ts
class a {
  constructor(){
    this.lazyNumber = () => 5 - 1;
  }
  
  printNumber(){
    console.log( this.lazyNumber() );
  }
}
```

The same fundamental thing is happening in your example.

---

You example is defining an attribute and the code that get runs when it's "called". `addMessage` is emitting a new value on the observable, that causes the listeners assinged above to react accordingly

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply.
So my next question is: when `addMessage` is called, it calls `this.newMessages.next(message);` which in turn triggers a call to 'create.map'... (via `this.newMessages.subscribe(this.create);`) which subscribes to the `this.updates`.
Why is `updates.scan()`... method called before 'create.map'... method (I checked this with the debugger) ?

Comment: @rejkid it shouldn't be, it's a confusingly nested application of my example above. The map creates a function that get's invoked by the scan... I think.